# iOS Distribution certificate not connecting when validating

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, archive

I am submitting my app to the App Store, but, when validating my app on archive, I get this error:

[image]

I do have the iOS Distribution certificate, as proved here:

[image]

Comment: Second screenshot is not a *Certificate* view, but a *Provision Profile* view.  In this case you are (presumably) viewing an App Store Provision Profile, as there are 0 *Devices:* added to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was because I had 2 WWDR certificates. I deleted the expired one and kept the valid one.

Answer (score 1):

Recently came up to the exact same problem which is solved by downloading and installing Apple WWDR certificate. You can find it here: [Apple WWDR certificate](http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer).

Short description:

> Apple’s World Wide Developer Relations (WWDR) certificate is available
>   from Apple at
>   http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer.
>   Download and install the certificate so that you can use it to certify
>   builds. The WWDR certificate links your development certificate to
>   Apple, completing the trust chain for your application.

Comment: When I download it, I enter my password, and then nothing happens.

Comment: After installing the WWDR certificate , you will need to generate a new Production/Development certifigate and update your provisioning profiles

Comment: There is also might be a problem with required iOS Distribution certificate+key being missed from the keychain at all.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin How do I do that?

Comment: Open *Keychain Access* app on your mac, make sure **login** keychain is active, select *My Certificates* category and type in search bar at the top right corner *iphone distr*. Do you see the certificate of your name / team?

Comment: @EugeneDubinin They're there, but they say that they have an invalid issuer.

Comment: It seems like the issue with WWDR cert described in the answer, then. Make sure the old WWDR is removed and new one is added. Its name is *Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority*

Comment: @EugeneDubinin When I double click on the file in downloads, it asks for my password, but then nothing happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106607/discussion-between-eugene-dubinin-and-swfapp).

Comment: @EugeneDubinin Shall we continue the discussion in chat now?

Comment: @EugeneDubinin Lets continue the discussion in chat.